# How do I programatically show "ripple effect" with MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ripple

Basically the title. I want to manually show the ripple effect on my collection of MUI's Buttons - the ripple effect works when I click the button, but I can't find a way to show the ripple effect programmatically.

Do I need to disable the MUI's ripple effect and then make my own ripple effect function, that I can attach to `onClick`?

```
{this.buttons.map((button) => (
    <React.Fragment key={button.name}>
        {button.render ? (
                <div className="col-3">
                    <Button
                        autoFocus={true}
                        className="w-100 p-3"
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        classes={{root: classes.button}}
                        disableElevation
                        onClick={() => {updateState(button.onClick(text))}}
                    >
                        {button.keyCode}
                    </Button>                               
                </div>
        ) : (<></>)}
    </React.Fragment>
))}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Button` uses [`ButtonBase`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js) which uses [`TouchRipple`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/fa475e270b5e121c550d41f3141ff5181dbb13f1/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L373) under the hood. Here is a snippet of `ButtonBase` definition:

```js
function ButtonBase(props) {
  // ...

  return (
    <ButtonBaseRoot>
      {children}
      <TouchRipple ref={rippleRef} center={centerRipple} {...TouchRippleProps} />
    </ButtonBaseRoot>
  )
}
```

There is no API to trigger the ripple manually. It's handled internally inside the button, so in order to do that, you need to create and control your own ripple component provided by MUI:

```
import TouchRipple from '@mui/material/ButtonBase/TouchRipple';
```

```js
const rippleRef = React.useRef(null);
const buttonRef = React.useRef(null);
const triggerRipple = () => {
  const container = buttonRef.current;
  const rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  rippleRef.current.start(
    {
      clientX: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
      clientY: rect.top + rect.height / 2,
    },
    // when center is true, the ripple doesn't travel to the border of the container
    { center: false },
  );

  setTimeout(() => rippleRef.current.stop({}), 320);
};

return (
  <div>
    <Button onClick={triggerRipple}>start ripple</Button>
    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" m={10}>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        ref={buttonRef}
        sx={{ display: 'relative' }}
      >
        My little ripple
        <TouchRipple ref={rippleRef} center />
      </Button>
    </Box>
  </div>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related answers

- [Is it possible to use the touch ripple effect of mui on a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67212941/9449426)

Comment: Optionally, the default ripple in the `Button` may be disabled via `disableRipple` prop, as a substitute `TouchRipple` is being used