# Is it possible to use the touch ripple effect of MUI on a div?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ripple-effect

I have read different answers of similar questions, but they are all old and don't seem to work in the latest version of MUI.

I need to apply the touch ripple effect on a div, but I can't use a button or a `ButtonBase` element because there is another button inside it.

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: The `TouchRipple` component uses a [`div`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/5d5128d251816bfccec0cb305a48ec553c399c4e/src/internal/TouchRipple.js#L216), so there's no problem in using it to wrap a `button` element.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can use `TouchRipple` to emulate the ripple effect. This component is undocumented, but you can see how it's used in the [`ButtonBase`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js) and learn to use it yourself.

First, you need to pass a ref to `TouchRipple` and call `ref.current.start(e)` or `ref.current.stop(e)` when you want to start or stop the effect respectively.

`e` is the event object. When you call `start(e)`, it needs the mouse or touch position (from `mousedown` or `touchstart` event) to know where to start the ripple effect ([Source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1617f4ee72920d40d0b0f9dac34f90b82dadf4bf/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js#L187-L189)). You can override this behavior by setting `center` props to `true`, which makes the ripple effect always start at the middle.

Below is the minimum working example to get you started:

```
function App() {
  const rippleRef = React.useRef(null);
  const onRippleStart = (e) => {
    rippleRef.current.start(e);
  };
  const onRippleStop = (e) => {
    rippleRef.current.stop(e);
  };

  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={onRippleStart}
      onMouseUp={onRippleStop}
      style={{
        display: "inline-block",
        padding: 8,
        position: "relative",
        border: "black solid 1px"
      }}
    >
      Button
      <TouchRipple ref={rippleRef} center={false} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66888248/how-do-i-programatically-show-ripple-effect-with-material-ui]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 16):

#### You Can Use `ButtonBase` API

With ButtonBase API you can pass `component` prop as `div` or any component you want

##### For Eg.

```js
import { ButtonBase, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ButtonBase component="div">
        <Typography fontSize="1.2rem">Hello, I'm a div with MUI Ripple Effect!</Typography>
    </ButtonBase>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Worked on my end

Comment: I know this is obvious out of context, but you may want to check your theme for something like this inside `components`:

`
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableRipple: true,
      },
    },
`

… in which case you'll need to overwrite this one time use with `disableRipple={false}` prop to ButtonBase.