# Is it possible to trigger Ripple effect manually in a react MUI Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have two arrow icon buttons in the User Interface that are used to navigate through the app. Now, I want to add the possibility to navigate using the keyboard arrows, right and left.

I am triggering the click event when the keyboard keys are pressed. The event happens, but the animation doesn't, so the user has no feedback if the app is moving or not.

Is it possible to trigger the ripple effect of the Button when the click event is triggered with the keyboard?

Comment: This here might answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888248/how-do-i-programatically-show-ripple-effect-with-mui

Comment: I saw that answer but the source code files say that they might turn TouchRipple component into a private one in this current version of MUI, so it won't be exposed. If that happens, it will be needed another way to do that. But for now, I'll try that approach, thank you!